# Is it possible to delete a record created during a flow interview that has been interrupted?

Tags: conditional, screen-flow, flow-interviews

I have a screen flow where a user creates a record in one screen, and in the next screen the user uploads a file to the record that has just been created. Then, the user presses a button that launches a subflow involving the newly created record and its file. If the user does the whole process, everything works fine.

However, if the user interrupts the screen flow (presses on the "X" to close the window) after creating the record but *before* uploading the file and pressing the button to launch the subflow, I would be interested in deleting the record created. I don't want the user to find a record lingering there with no file attached because the user had not finished the process (and I always want them to use the Screen Flow to create the record, upload its file and launch the subflow).

Is there a way to indicate what actions should be taken if a flow interview is interrupted at a given moment? In my case, I would want to delete the newly created record.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this would be to have 2 record types called "in progress" and "complete" (this could also be done with a field). Assign "in progress" by default and "complete" just before the Subflow is launched, then use a scheduled flow to get all the "in progress" records that have not been completed and delete them.
I hope this answer is able to be of use to someone :)